# Difference between declaring type of variable

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

I already have a variable called

```
Image spriteImage;
```

later on in the code I state what it is

```
Image spriteImage = new Image("content/man.png");
```

this code crashes my Slick2D application.
What is the difference between

```
Image spriteImage = new Image("content/man.png");
```

and

```
spriteImage = new Image("content/man.png");
```

(Which actually works)

Answer (score 3):

If by "crash" you mean "won't compile," then the reason is that, whenever you state `Image spriteImage` (or any other type/name combination) in a scope, you're defining a new variable. If you've already had a similar statement, then it will fail to compile saying that you've re-declared the same variable twice.

The statement:

`Image spriteImage = new Image("content/man.png");`

declares a **new** variable called `spriteImage`, whereas the statement:

`spriteImage = new Image("content/man.png");`

is setting the value of `spriteImage`, a variable which already exists, to `new Image(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be shadowing a variable.

If outside a method you have

```
Image spriteImage
```

And then inside the method you do

```
Image spriteImage = (...);
```

You are assigning a local variable `spriteImage`

If you do

```
spriteImage = (...);
```

Then you are assigning the previously declared `spriteImage` (presumably an instance variable)

When you just assign the local one, you leave the instance one as `null`, and I'm guessing you try to use it and there's a null pointer that causes openGL to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You've already declared **Image spriteImage** but haven't initialized it.

```
    spriteImage = new Image("content/man.png");
```

The above is initializing it, however

```
    Image spriteImage = new Image("content/man.png");
```

is declaring a local Image variable, which is shadowing the other variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your redeclaring a variable. spriteImage is already an Image so you can't declare it as an Image. Another solution is to just use:

```
Image spriteImage = new Image("content/man.png");
```

and not declare it above in this statement.

```
Image spriteImage;
```

This is also acceptable and you don't declare spriteImage twice.